# How to reset dmenu app launching preferences in i3

Tags: i3, manjaro, dmenu

I accidentally selected "terminal" instead of "background" in `dmenu` when I launched a GUI applications. Now, every time I launch the app I get an unwanted terminal. How do I reset the `dmenu` preference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inside `~/.config/dmenu-recent` there are two text files called `background` and `terminal`. Edit the appropriate one in a text editor, and delete the line with your app's name. This will reset the `dmenu` app preference.